# How do frameworks like angular contain css within a component?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

More of a curious question rather than solving an actual problem.

How do frameworks like angular contain CSS within a component and prevent the CSS from leaking all over the page?

Comment: See http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

Comment: I not sure if it's what you are looking for, but you always have a class option. I, for example, wanted to use bootstrap-buttons, so every button got a `class="btn btn-default"`. Every button which does not have this, will be a "normal" button..

Comment: ShadowDOM: https://scotch.io/tutorials/all-the-ways-to-add-css-to-angular-2-components

Comment: @bene I usually do that too, but with that approach an element with the class `btn-default` elsewhere on the page would be affected. Not so much an issue if you wrote all the code yourself, but it's an issue if you combine elements/templates/angular components that other people wrote.

haim and mondjunge linked to the ShadowDOM which looks like a solution that angular 2 uses to prevent this

Comment: Thanks. This looks like something ng-style would do but I haven't read it in detail.. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular 2 uses the ShadowDOM concept which allows for CSS to be contained within a component.

By default Angular 2 uses "emulation" which means it emulates a ShadowDOM implementation so that its more likely to work on older browsers.
It can be set to use the native browser implementation (but will only work if the browser supports it).

As a side note, ShadowDOM can be completely turned off in angular 2 and CSS will leak as you expect it.

Answer (score 1):

In default `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` CSS is added to `<head>` for all components. Component tags and the elements in their template get a unique CSS class added and the selectors of the styles are rewritten by Angular2 before they are added to `<head>` to only match the specific component where the styles were added to.

If `ViewEncapsulation.Native` is used for browsers with native shadow DOM support, the styles are added directly into the component. 
If the browser doesn't have native shadow DOM support and webcomponents polyfills are loaded this works similar as Angular2 with `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated`